# UIActionSheet buttonIndex 

Tags: iphone, ios, uiactionsheet

I have a UIActionSheet in my app that defaults to having 4 buttons. If a user customises an image the action sheet gains an extra 5th button allowing the user to reset this image.

I'm using this delegate method to determine which action sheet button has been clicked:

```
-(void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
```

The problem is the cancel button is at buttonIndex 2 by default but when the 5th button is present it is at buttonIndex 3. Is there anyway from knowing the buttonIndex you can access the title/name of the action sheet button?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes you can ask the action sheet for the button title at given index using :

```
-(NSString *)buttonTitleAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex;
```

Alternatively, `UIActionSheet` defines a property :

```
@property(nonatomic) NSInteger cancelButtonIndex;
```

Comment: Ah fantastic that works perfectly. Completely missed that method when looking through the docs. Thank you for such a swift response.

Comment: Decided to use the cancelButtonIndex property in the end, as if the cancel button title ever changes (unlikely) the code won't break.

Comment: Make sure buttonIndex is >=0 and < actionSheet.numberOfButtons or buttonTitleAtIndex will throw an exception.

Comment: Th best is to use cancelButtonIndex AND buttonTitleAtIndex for "other buttons" as ios can decide to scumble the buttons (cancel may be at top or bottom, destroy also)